# Naive Question regarding feature selection

Tags: machine-learning, feature-selection

I have two labelled classes, 500 examples of each, 4500 features for each of them. So the dataframe is 1000X4500.

Is it possible to devise a model which uses all the 4500 features and gives 100% accuracy, and then remove out unimportant features one by one till I get an accuracy of 85% (i.e. moving from a completely overfit model to a more generalized one with 85% accuracy)?

So basically the purpose is to filter out unnecessary features. Does such a method even exist in machine learning?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to devise a model which uses all the 4500 features and gives 100% accuracy

Not necessarily. As an extreme example, suppose all 1,000 observations have the same feature vector. In that case, all any model can do is predict the same class for every observation, so it would be 50% accurate. I'm sure your data isn't that bad, but it comes to show that whether you can achieve 100% accuracy on training data depends on the feature vectors.

> and then remove out unimportant features one by one till I get an accuracy of 85% (i.e. moving from a completely overfit model to a more generalized one with 85% accuracy)?

This is unlikely to be a good method to maximize predictive accuracy in new data. Certainly, if you have 85% accuracy in the training data, you can expect to get lower accuracy with new data.

I would suggest instead conventional feature-selection or regularization methods, such as logistic regression with a lasso penalty.

Comment: thanks for your reply, will try applying your suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Yes possible**, although you can't always guarantee to exactly start at $100\%$ accuracy on all datasets and on all learning algorithms. But I think your point was not that. I think your point was to start around some extremely high accuracy due to over-fitting, then gradually generalize until you reach your sweet-spot.

I think that your logic is correct and you are onto something. In fact, I think this is why some learning algorithms include parameters that allow you to tune how aggressively the resultant models over fits the learning set.

For example, if you choose [Random Forests](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier), you can start with $\texttt{n_features} = 4,500$ and $\texttt{n_estimators}=1000$ (the latter parameter becomes probably irrelevant as all trees will agree as there is no randomness after choosing all features).

This should give you highest classification accuracy on the learning set. You can test this this on the testing set, and notice that its performance is poor on the testing set.

Then you can repeat the above but with $\texttt{n_features} = 4,500 - 100 = 4,400$ instead. And test on both learning and testing sets.

Keep repeating that many times, each time with a further reduction of $\texttt{n_features}$ until you reach $\texttt{n_features} = 1$. When $\texttt{n_features} = 1$, then you will create a highly random decision forest that is is most likely no longer over-fitting, but rather under-fitting.

If you plot that, you should get something like this (classification error = 1 - accuracy):
[image]

You can also try Extremely-randomized Trees (ET). With this, setting $\texttt{n_features} = 1$ will be way more random (fully random trees), but you will also need to start with much more than $\texttt{n_features} = 4,500$.

Comment: thanks for getting my point (I know I couldnt phrase it properly). And thanks for an elaborate explanation.So another question I have is, that is there any method to rank 4500 features according to their contribution to accuracy. So that by looking at that plot I would know that if I remove these exact 200 features then my accuracy would be exactly that.( i.e. Num_features vs accuracy or Name_feature vs accuracy)

Comment: If you look at tree in the trees that are generated by random forests, and look at the features that make up each tree, features that appear first closer to the root of the tree are more important than those that appear further lower down the branches. So you can use random forests for deciding features importance as well. But this is just one example, there are many other ways of ranking features by their importance.